# Pasting a Range inside HTML code

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to copy an excel range to paste it into an html but for some reason, all I am getting is "True" inside the cell. I wonder why is not pasting the range values? This is part of the code. Thank you

```
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Sheets("DONTCHANGE").Range("A3:G28")
  rng.Copy

    "<tr><td align='justify' colspan=3>" & rng.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues) & "</td>" & _
```

Comment: It is indeed part of the code - you have chopped a line up! If the & _ is irrelevant maybe remove it. What would the expected result look like?

Comment: Thank you, yes, the &_ is not irrelevant since the code continues in the next line. I am trying to copy a portion of an excel table (characters and numbers) 5 columns to be exact